# Compare and contrast Caliburn v. MVVM Light Toolkit (mainly for Silverlight)?

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, mvvm

I want to learn more about a MVVM framework but I don't have a lot of time to devote.  Does someone have experience with Caliburn (or micro Caliburn) and MVVM Light Toolkit and can give some reasons to start with one framework over the other?  This would mainly be for Silverlight development.

Or perhaps is there another framework that might be easier to start with?

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at this nice article that provides a summary and comparison of various MVVM frameworks - http://www.japf.fr/2009/10/a-quick-tour-of-existing-mvvm-frameworks/. The choice of an MVVM framework depends on the time available and the complexity of your project. If you wish to learn how to use a MVVM framework, it is best to work on a small project first in which you explore one or more frameworkss. MVVMLight and Caliburn are popular frameworks and they are used by both Silverlight and Windows Phone 7 developers. There are numerous sample applications available on the web that illustrate the use of these frameworks.

HTH, indyfromoz