# MVVM Light Toolkit vs Cinchv2?

Tags: mvvm

I'm trying use and choose good MVVM Framework and there are plenty of them, so choice is really difficult.

I'm wondering about 2 of them - CinchV2 (Sacha Barber) and MVVM Light Toolkit (Laurent Bugnion).

It's really confusing to read articles about them and right now it's much harder for me to decide. Is there any comparision of them both?

I'll be glad if anyone who used CinchV2 or MVVM Light or both of them, could write his opinion (what is missing, what is better etc.) it would be really usefull.

Comment: checkout answer to 4235491 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235491).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using mvvmlight in a medium size LOB application and its great.  Its got my vote for 'just working' and simplicity.